# Google Maps API v3: Cover Entire Map with an OverlayView

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6

So, I've been banging my head on my desk trying to optimize this kind of hacky solution I've come up with for my problem. I'm currently using the following code to re-draw my overlay each time the center is changed - however this doesn't quite keep up on mobile devices (will cover once draw call completes, but you can see non-masked areas while dragging):

```
export default class MapOverlay extends google.maps.OverlayView {
  constructor (bounds, image, map) {
    super()

    this.bounds_ = bounds
    this.image_ = image
    this.map_ = map
    this.div_ = null

    this.setMap(map)
  }

  onAdd () {
    var div = document.getElementById('map-overlay')
    this.div_ = div
    var panes = this.getPanes()
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div)

    // add a listener to re-mask the new bounds on each map drag
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map_, 'center_changed', () => { this.draw() })
  }

  draw () {
    // get current bounds, mask that junk yo
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection()
    var bounds = this.map_.getBounds()
    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getSouthWest())
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getNorthEast())
    this.bounds_ = bounds

    var div = this.div_
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px'
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px'
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px'
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px'
  }
}
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is just set custom bounds to (85, -180), (-85, 180) and have my OverlayView cover the entire map without having to redraw - however when I set this.bounds_ to what SHOULD cover the entire map - my same ne/sw calculations return completely wrong results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!